# Duplicate value while using Group By

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT location,special,price FROM `tickets` 
WHERE event = 'food' GROUP BY location
```

[image]

Comment: When using group by all the properties in select must be in the group by clause or used as an aggregate function, sum, count avg etc.

Comment: you seem to have other columns than location, special, price . Are you sure you actually do not have duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to not have duplicate results in your rows you can choose only distinct result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT location,special,price FROM tickets WHERE event = 'food' GROUP BY location
```

Comment: @clearlight thank you for putting this comment. I have added whatever my assumed fix is as there is no actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want, (assuming its mysql) the following:

```sql
SELECT location, ANY_VALUE(special) special, ANY_VALUE(price) price
FROM tickets
WHERE event='food'
GROUP BY location ;
```

ANY_VALUE is strange aggregate function out of normal db standards that returns one of the values arbitarily.